# Thread function malfunctions, incomplete output and segmentation error

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, pthreads

The following code is supposed to create one Producer thread and one Consumer thread. The Producer creates random numbers, adds them to a circular buffer(push_back()) and then writes them in an output txt called prod_out.txt. The Consumer "consumes" these numbers by poping them (pop_front()) and then writing them in an output txt called cons_out.txt. For a call like this ./a.out 1 1 10 20 1 the arguements are as follows: there will be 1 producer, 1 consumer, 10 is circular buffer's capacity, 20 random numbers will be generated and the seed for rand_r is 1.

If the buffer's capacity is smaller than the ammount of random nums to be generated the program only writes 9 numbers in the consumers' txt, while the producers' txt is just fine. If they are the same then the consumers' txt does not get created and producers' txt misses one number (namely the last one, just like the consumer txt does when the capacity is smaller than the numbers generated).

**This is the main function**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prodcons.h"


FILE * fp;
int rc;
circular_buffer* cb;
int fileW, my_random;
pthread_mutex_t Mutex;
pthread_cond_t Condition;
args* t_args;

void* Producers(void* fargs){
printf("I am Producer and I am not locked\n");
args* f_args= fargs;
rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
printf("I am Producer and I am locked\n");
if (rc != 0) {  
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_lock() is %d\n", rc);
    pthread_exit(&rc);
}
printf(" The ruler of all mutexes has passed from here and shall start 
creating random numbers\n");
for(int i=0; i < *(f_args->rand_count); i++){

    if(i==cb->capacity){
        printf(" Your producer king will now sleep\n");
        rc = pthread_cond_signal(&Condition);
        if (rc != 0) {  
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_signal() is %d\n", 
    rc);
            pthread_exit(&rc);
        }

        rc = pthread_cond_wait(&Condition, &Mutex);
        if (rc != 0) {  
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_wait() is %d\n", 
    rc);
            pthread_exit(&rc);
        }

    }

    my_random =rand_r(f_args->seed)%255;
    printf ( "Creating random number %d.\n", my_random);
    cb_push_back(cb, &my_random);
    if(i==0){
        fp=fopen("prod_in.txt", "w");
    }else{
        fp=fopen("prod_in.txt", "a");
    }
    fprintf(fp, "Producer %d: %d\n", f_args->ID, my_random);
    fclose(fp);
}
printf("I am going to go to signal the consumer.\n");

rc = pthread_cond_signal(&Condition);
if (rc != 0) {  
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_signal() is %d\n", rc);
    pthread_exit(&rc);
}

rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
if (rc != 0) {  
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_unlock() is %d\n", rc);
    pthread_exit(&rc);
}

}

void* Consumer(void* t1){
int *threadId = (int *) t1;
printf("I am Consumer and I am NOT locked\n");
rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
printf("I am Consumer and I am locked\n");
if (rc != 0) {  
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_lock() is %d\n", rc);
    pthread_exit(&rc);
}
if(cb->count == 0){
    rc = pthread_cond_wait(&Condition, &Mutex);
    if (rc != 0) {  
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_wait() is %d\n", rc);
        pthread_exit(&rc);
    }
}
int counter = cb-> count;
for (int j=0; j<= counter; j++){
    printf("Consumer will now consume with items remaining %d.\n", (int)cb- 
 >count);


    if(j==0){
        fp=fopen("cons_out.txt", "w");

    }else{
        fp=fopen("cons_out.txt", "a");
    }
    printf("I will now write the following %d, %d inside the 
file.\n",*threadId,my_random);
    fprintf(fp, "Consumer %d: %d\n",*threadId, my_random);
    cb_pop_front(cb,&my_random);
    if(cb->count == 0){
        rc = pthread_cond_signal(&Condition);
        if (rc != 0) {  
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_signal() is %d\n", 
rc);
            pthread_exit(&rc);
        }

        rc = pthread_cond_wait(&Condition, &Mutex);
        if (rc != 0) {  
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_wait() is %d\n", 
rc);
            pthread_exit(&rc);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
if (rc != 0) {  
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_unlock() is %d\n", rc);
    pthread_exit(&rc);
}
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
if (argc !=6){
    printf("ERROR: the program should take five arguments!\n");
    exit(-1);
}

if(atoi(argv[1])!= 1 || atoi(argv[2])!= 1){
    printf("ERROR:This program only functions for one producer and 
consumer.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
int main_seed = atoi(argv[5]);
int main_rand = atoi(argv[4]);
int buffer_size =  atoi(argv[3]);
cb=(circular_buffer*) malloc(sizeof(struct circular_buffer));
t_args=(args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
cb_init(cb, buffer_size, sizeof(int));
t_args->seed= &main_seed;
t_args->rand_count= &main_rand;
t_args->ID=1;
int t1=1;
pthread_t p1, c1;
printf ( "I am the ruler of all mutexes. I now shall initialise the 
mutex\n");
rc = pthread_mutex_init(&Mutex, NULL);
if (rc != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_init() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
}

rc = pthread_cond_init(&Condition, NULL);
if (rc != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_init() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
}
rc = pthread_create(&p1, NULL, Producers, (void*)t_args); //cast σε void????
if (rc != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
}

rc = pthread_create(&c1, NULL,Consumer,  &t1);
if (rc != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
}

void *status;
rc = pthread_join(p1, &status);
if (rc != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);       
}
printf("Main(): Thread %d terminated successfully.\n", *(int *) status);

rc = pthread_join(c1, &status);
if (rc != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);       
}
printf("Main(): Thread %d terminated successfully.\n", *(int *) status);

rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&Mutex);
if (rc != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_destroy() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);       
}

rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&Condition);
if (rc != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_destroy() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);       
}
free(cb);
free(t_args);

return 1;


}
```

**This is a header file with the 2 structs and the circular buffer functions**

```
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"



typedef struct circular_buffer
{
void *buffer;     // data buffer
void *buffer_end; // end of data buffer
size_t capacity;  // maximum number of items in the buffer
size_t count;     // number of items in the buffer
size_t sz;        // size of each item in the buffer
void *head;       // pointer to head
void *tail;       // pointer to tail
}circular_buffer;

typedef struct args
{
int ID;             //Unique ID from 1 to n 
int* seed;          //The seed used for rand_r
int* rand_count;    //The number of random generated numbers
}args;

void cb_push_back(circular_buffer *cb, const void *item);
void cb_pop_front(circular_buffer *cb, void *item);
void cb_init(circular_buffer *cb, size_t capacity, size_t sz);
void cb_free(circular_buffer *cb);
```

**In this file are the implementetions of the circular buffer functions**

```
#include "prodcons.h"

//initialize circular buffer
//capacity: maximum number of elements in the buffer
//sz: size of each element 
void cb_init(circular_buffer *cb, size_t capacity, size_t sz)
{
cb->buffer = malloc(capacity * sz);
if(cb->buffer == NULL){
    printf("Could not allocate memory..Exiting! \n");
    exit(1);
    }
    // handle error
cb->buffer_end = (char *)cb->buffer + capacity * sz;
cb->capacity = capacity;
cb->count = 0;
cb->sz = sz;
cb->head = cb->buffer;
cb->tail = cb->buffer;
}

//destroy circular buffer
void cb_free(circular_buffer *cb)
{
free(cb->buffer);
// clear out other fields too, just to be safe
}

//add item to circular buffer
void cb_push_back(circular_buffer *cb, const void *item)
{
if(cb->count == cb->capacity)
    {
        printf("Access violation. Buffer is full\n");
        exit(1);
    }
memcpy(cb->head, item, cb->sz);
cb->head = (char*)cb->head + cb->sz;
if(cb->head == cb->buffer_end)
    cb->head = cb->buffer;
cb->count++;
}

//remove first item from circular item
void cb_pop_front(circular_buffer *cb, void *item)
{
if(cb->count == 0)
    {
        printf("Access violation. Buffer is empy\n");
        exit(1);
}
memcpy(item, cb->tail, cb->sz);
cb->tail = (char*)cb->tail + cb->sz;
if(cb->tail == cb->buffer_end)
    cb->tail = cb->buffer;
cb->count--;
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing the warnings in your code. Neither of those functions (Producer or Consumer) return values you promised you would in their return type declarations. Then, in a debugger, let the crash come and analyze where it happens, back tracing to see what went wrong.  And fyi, you have an unguarded concurrency issue on `rc` in this code. Just saying.

Comment: The compiler (lubuntu 64 bits) gives me no errors, warnings or notes, also the functions are defined as void so they don't have to return anything. Their only output can be seen in their respective output txt and the command line

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` would be a good place to start. And those functions are correctly declared as returning `void *` not `void`; you're just not following through with that promise. There's a world of difference from `void *` and `void`, and you had better know what it is by this point. Once fixed (I fixed it by elimination, which also fixed the `rc` issue I mentioned) and addressing a few other issues, your code runs correctly.

Comment: Thank  you for the help but unforunately the deadline for the assignment was due to June 8th. The pointers did help me though. I'll be carefull so as not to make the same mistakes in the future. Thanks again.